# Why does this code generates unexpected output?

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging

```cpp
vector<int> arr = {11, 10, 13, 12, 19, 14};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
    int min = arr[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        if (arr[j] < min)
            // min=j;
            swap(min, arr[j]);
    }
    // cout<<min<<" ";
}
```

I know the correct selection sort algorithm but i don't know how this code is actually working

Comment: The code doesn't produce _any_ output. What is the expected output? Also `std::swap(min, arr[j]);` will swap the wrong thing. `swap(arr[i], arr[j]);` would be the right thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Why not just use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: That looks a lot closer to bubble sort than selection sort.

Answer (score 5):

`swap(min, arr[j]);` will swap the wrong thing since `min` is a **copy** of `arr[i]`.

If you want it to `swap(arr[i], arr[j]);` you need to make `min` a **reference** to `arr[i]`:

```cpp
for (std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < arr.size(); i++) {
    int& min = arr[i];                             // <- note `int&`
    for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        if (arr[j] < min) {
            std::swap(min, arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
//for(int val : arr) std::cout << val << ' ';
```

Note: Your comment in the code printing `min` is confusing. Printing should preferably be done *after* the bubblesorting is done.

Comment: My personal preference would be that `min` is instead something like `minIdx`, and that will force the `std::swap` to explicitly reference the array twice, instead of one implicit and one explicit reference.

Comment: @sweenish Not a bad turn. I'd prefer to not have a "proxy" at all in this case.

Comment: Definitely. This is in the context of "I'm writing a sort manually for some reason."

Answer (score 0):

You are getting unexpected output because your code is missing the exchange (swap) of smallest element found in unsorted sublist (nested loop) with the left most unsorted element, which is `arr[i]`.

Just add following code after nested loop (at the place where you commented out printing `min`) and you will get the expected output

```
                if (min != arr[i]) {
                    arr[i] = min;
                }
```

That said, this is inefficient way of implementing selection sort because your nested loop may end up swapping of elements multiple times. Better to keep track of index of smallest element in inner loop in `min` (`min` should hold index `i` instead of value at `i`<sup>th</sup> index before entering nested loop) and, after nested loop, swap `a[min]` with the `a[i]` if `a[i]` and `a[min]` are different.